# Xcode app for macOS. This is how I setup to get audio from usb mic input. Worked a year ago, now doesn't. Why

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, audio

Here is my audio init code.  My app responds when queue buffers are ready, but all data in buffer is zero.  Checking   sound in system preferences shows that USB Audio CODEC in sound input dialog is active.  AudioInit() is called right after app launches.

```
{
    #pragma mark user data struct
    typedef struct MyRecorder
    {
        AudioFileID recordFile;
        SInt64 recordPacket;
        Float32 *pSampledData;
        MorseDecode *pMorseDecoder;

    } MyRecorder;

    #pragma mark utility functions
    void CheckError(OSStatus error, const char *operation)
    {
        if(error == noErr) return;

        char errorString[20];
        // see if it appears to be a 4 char code
        *(UInt32*)(errorString + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
        if (isprint(errorString[1]) && isprint(errorString[2]) &&
            isprint(errorString[3]) && isprint(errorString[4]))
        {
            errorString[0] = errorString[5] = '\'';
            errorString[6] = '\0';
        }

        else
        {
            sprintf(errorString, "%d", (int)error);

        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", operation, errorString);
    }

    OSStatus MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(Float64 *outSampleRate)
    {
        OSStatus error;
        AudioDeviceID deviceID = 0;
        AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress;
        UInt32 propertySize;
        propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
        propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
        propertyAddress.mElement = 0;
        propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
        error = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                                    &propertyAddress,
                                                    0,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &propertySize,
                                                    &deviceID);

        if(error)
            return error;

        propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
        propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
        propertyAddress.mElement = 0;
        propertySize = sizeof(Float64);
        error = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID,
                                                    &propertyAddress,
                                                    0,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &propertySize,
                                                    outSampleRate);

        return error;
    }

    static int MyComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format,
                                         AudioQueueRef queue,
                                         float seconds)
    {
        int packets, frames, bytes;
        frames = (int)ceil(seconds * format->mSampleRate);
        if(format->mBytesPerFrame > 0)
        {
            bytes = frames * format->mBytesPerFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            UInt32 maxPacketSize;
            if(format->mBytesPerPacket > 0)
            {
                // constant packet size
                maxPacketSize = format->mBytesPerPacket;
            }
            else
            {
                // get the largest single packet size possible
                UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
                CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                                                 kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize,
                                                 &maxPacketSize,
                                                 &propertySize),
                           "Couldn't get queues max output packet size");
            }
            if(format->mFramesPerPacket > 0)
                packets = frames / format->mFramesPerPacket;
            else
                // worst case scenario: 1 frame in a packet
                packets = frames;
            // sanity check
            if(packets == 0)
                packets = 1;
            bytes = packets * maxPacketSize;

        }
        return bytes;
    }


    extern void bridgeToMainThread(MorseDecode *pDecode);

    static int callBacks = 0;
    // ---------------------------------------------
    static void MyAQInputCallback(void *inUserData,
                                  AudioQueueRef inQueue,
                                  AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
                                  UInt32 inNumPackets,
                                  const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc)
    {
        MyRecorder *recorder = (MyRecorder*)inUserData;
        Float32 *pAudioData = (Float32*)(inBuffer->mAudioData);
        recorder->pMorseDecoder->pBuffer = pAudioData;
        recorder->pMorseDecoder->bufferSize = inNumPackets;
        bridgeToMainThread(recorder->pMorseDecoder);
        CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inQueue,
                                           inBuffer,
                                           0,
                                           NULL),
                   "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
        printf("packets = %ld, bytes = %ld\n",(long)inNumPackets,(long)inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize);
        callBacks++;
        //printf("\ncallBacks = %d\n",callBacks);
        //if(callBacks == 0)
            //audioStop();
    }


    static AudioQueueRef queue = {0};
    static MyRecorder recorder = {0};
    static AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;


    void audioInit()
    {
        // set up format
        memset(&recordFormat,0,sizeof(recordFormat));
        recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
        recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 32;
        recordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = recordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(Float32);
        recordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        //recordFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
        recordFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked;
        MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);
        UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);
        CheckError(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo,
                                          0,
                                          NULL,
                                          &propSize,
                                          &recordFormat),
                    "AudioFormatProperty failed");


        recorder.pMorseDecoder = MorseDecode::pInstance();
        recorder.pMorseDecoder->m_sampleRate = recordFormat.mSampleRate;
        //    recorder.pMorseDecoder->setCircularBuffer();

        //set up queue

        CheckError(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat,
                                      MyAQInputCallback,
                                      &recorder,
                                      NULL,
                                      kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                                      0,
                                      &queue),
                   "AudioQueueNewInput failed");
        UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
        CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                                         kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription,
                                         &recordFormat,
                                         &size), "Couldn't get queue's format");

        // set up buffers and enqueue

        const int kNumberRecordBuffers = 3;

        int bufferByteSize = MyComputeRecordBufferSize(&recordFormat, queue, AUDIO_BUFFER_DURATION);
        for(int bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < kNumberRecordBuffers; bufferIndex++)
        {
            AudioQueueBufferRef buffer;
            CheckError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(queue,
                                                bufferByteSize,
                                                &buffer),
                       "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");
            CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue,
                                               buffer,
                                               0,
                                               NULL),
                       "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
        }
    }

    void audioRun()
    {
        CheckError(AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL), "AudioQueueStart failed");
    }

    void audioStop()
    {
        CheckError(AudioQueuePause(queue), "AudioQueuePause failed");
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I make my app list in the microphone access list?  I am working in Xcode and running using debugger.  Do I need to do something to install it so macOS recognizes it?

Comment: You can't. This behaviour is intended to give _users_ control over which applications can access the microphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the new macOS 'microphone privacy' setting, which, if set to 'no access' for your app, will cause precisely this behaviour.  So:

1. Open the System Preferences pane.
2. Click on 'Security and Privacy'.
3. Select the Privacy tab.
4. Click on 'Microphone' in the left-hand pane.
5. Locate your app in the right-hand pane and tick the checkbox next to it.

Then restart your app and test it.

Tedious, no?

---

Edit: As stated in the comments, you can't directly request microphone access, but you can detect whether it has been granted to your app or not by calling [`[AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624613-authorizationstatusformediatype).

Comment: I am not specifically using the micro phone, the device called "USB Audio CODEC" of type "USB".  I have selected that in the sound box of system preferences under Input tab.  It shows activity in input level indicator.

Comment: 'Microphone' is Apple-speak for any form of audio input in this context, and the signal in the System Preferences pane is incidental.  What is being blocked is the signal to **your** app, and the steps above will fix it.

Comment: Well then I need to know how to proceed.  Is there some way for my app to ask for access which gets passed on to user who can permit access?  When I go the privacy tab I don't see my app.  How does it get added to the list of apps that want access that I can grant access to?

Comment: The first time your app attempts to access the 'microphone', MacOS pops up a box asking the user whether or not he / she want s to permit it.  If they say yes, then MacOS remember that choice and permits access to your app thereafter.  Your app will also appear in the privacy tab with the checkbox ticked.  If they say no, then your app will receive a silent audio stream thereafter and it will appear in the privacy tab with the checkbox unticked.

Comment: You can't directly influence any of this behaviour, but see my edit.